# Calling an Entity Framework class inside my console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, console-application

I have created a new console application using Visual Studio 2012, and I mapped my database tables using Entity Framework. Now I use to do the following when I worked with web applications such as MVC, is to create a new object representing the entities and reference all the available entities:

```
class Program
{
    SEntities sd = new SEntities();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
            sd.Levels.Add(new Level() { Name = "from CA" });
            sd.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

but this will raise the following error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.sd'    .....\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs    16  17  ConsoleApplication1

I read some articles and it seems that I need to reference Entity Framework class inside my console application by opening a `using` block as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (SEntities sd = new SEntities())
        {
            sd.Levels.Add(new Level() { Name = "from CA" });
            sd.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is, why I cannot follow the first approach as wrapping the whole method inside a using block sound not bit strange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to use a non-static field in a static method. One that is not declared in the static method's scope to be a bit more specific. The `using` block is not what is causing the second block of code to work. The reason that it works is because you have the non-static field inside the static method instead of outside of it.

However, you should in fact use the `using` block because that will ensure that the context is disposed.

Comment: ok I got your point, so is there a way to avoid using the "using" block ?

Comment: The `using` block just ensures that the `Dispose()` method of the context is called; releasing the unmanaged resources. In all reality you don't have to use it but best practices will state otherwise. An alternative would be a `try/finally`. In the `finally` manually call `Dispose()`.

Comment: but I am unable to reference the "sd" in my case unless I pass the Entities class inside my using block.

Comment: Just use `SEntities sd = new SEntities();` inside your method instead of outside of it.